# Bootbox modal not appearing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I am working with the latest versions:

- jQuery 3.0.0.1
- Bootstrap 3.3.6.1
- Bootbox 4.4.0

My HTML:

```
A+ Certification, Grad. 2011 Comptia 
<a id="e1658b80-0c48-e611-8277-14feb5fbeae8" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Delete this entry" href="/[controller]/[action]/e1658b80-0c48-e611-8277-14feb5fbeae8"> </a>
```

My JavaScript, embedded in the page directly beneath the delete link:

```
<stript type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#39b75c0a-0a48-e611-8277-14feb5fbeae8').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm('Do you wish to delete this entry?', function(result) {
      if (result) { window.location = $(this).attr('href'); }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

My headers:

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js">
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js">
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js">
<script src="/Scripts/bootbox.js">
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
<script src="/Scripts/metisMenu.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.peity.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mask.js">
<script src="/Scripts/script.common.js">
<script src="/Scripts/script.internal.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/inspinia.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/style.internal.css">
```

(These are not yet minified; the production output will be.)

Right now I have gotten the setup such that an attempt to click on the delete anchor will not actually cause the browser to follow the anchor `href` (which is good, we want to warn the user using the modal!), but for some reason the modal dialog refuses to display. No greying of the screen, nothing.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is Bootstrap 3.3.6.1 compatible with jQuery 3.0.0.1? Did you try to open a boostrap (not bootbox) modal? Are you getting any js error?

Comment: 3.3.6.1 has no max version set as a dependency: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap the prior version 3.3.6.0 did https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/3.3.6 **EDIT:** Well, whattya know… the NuGet packages aren’t exactly being built right, as they don’t reflect a proper maxversion dependency for jQuery: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple things you can do to debug this:**

Which browser are you testing this?

Install firebug or in chrome use F12 to see if you get any error.Post that error if you are getting if.

Use console.log to test that on click you are actually invoking and getting inside the click function you wrote. print logs before and after `e.preventDefault();`

If above things do not give any positive results you have library
    conflicts/incompatibility issue. Try checking the versions of the JS libraries you are using.

I suggest to first refer the example and the technique used in the http://bootboxjs.com/#usage and try using the same libraries they have used and in the same order.

Also the HTML should be like this to use glyphicons:

```
<a href="#" data-bb="confirm" class="btn btn-default"><i id="e1658b80-0c48-e611-8277-14feb5fbeae8" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Delete this entry" href="/[controller]/[action]/e1658b80-0c48-e611-8277-14feb5fbeae8"></i></a>
```

Comment: Actually, if you read my first comment (above) it was a dependency issue. The NuGet package for BootStrap 3.3.6.1 did not set a max version for jQuery, whereas 3.3.6.0 did ( < 3 ). Since I had only ever worked with BootStrap since v3.3.6.0 came out, I thought the lack of an upper dependency really meant that .1 was compatible with jQuery 3.

Comment: Oh, yes. I feel rather stupid for blindly trusting the NuGet dependency rules. Not every package is set up properly, apparently.